# Not able to perform SingleClick functionfor set coordinates

Tags: excel, vba, winapi

I am not able to make clicks on mentioned coordinates in code as follows

```
'Declare mouse events
    Public Declare Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long
    Public Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dx As Long, ByVal dy As Long, ByVal cButtons As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
    Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2
    Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4
    Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN As Long = &H8
    Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP As Long = &H10
    'Declare sleep
    Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
    Private Sub SingleClick()
      mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
      mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
    End Sub
    Public Sub CreateAWorkbook()
    
    Dim Asset_Id As String
    Dim Current_Mark As String
    Dim DateTimeStamp As String, WorkbookName As String
    
    SetCursorPos 481, 38
    SingleClick
    SetCursorPos 336, 69
    SingleClick
    
    Asset_Id = Range("F2").Value
    Current_Mark = Range("I2").Value
    
    If IsEmpty(Range("F2").Value) = False And IsEmpty(Range("I2").Value) = False Then
    MessageToDisplay = "The Asset id is : " & Asset_Id & " and current mark is: " & Current_Mark
    MsgBox (MessageToDisplay)
    Else
    MessageToDisplay = "The Asset id is not present"
    MsgBox (MessageToDisplay)
    
    End If
    
    
    End Sub
```

Right now cursor just hover over the coordinates instead of making a click. Can anyone please help?
[Image to show clicks area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kC4d.png)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem.

1. You should confirm that the target coordinates are clickable when
   executing `CreateAWorkbook`
2. `mouse_event` has been replaced by [`SendInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput).
3. You don't need to use `SetCursorPos`, both `mouse_event` and `SendInput` can specify coordinates.

Here is the usage in C/C++:

`mouse_event`

```
void mouseClick(int x, int y) {

    int fScreenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    int fScreenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
    int dx = MulDiv(x, 65535, fScreenWidth);
    int dy = MulDiv(y, 65535, fScreenHeight);
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN| MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, dx, dy, 0, 0);
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP| MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, dx, dy, 0, 0);
}
```

`SendInput`

```
void mouseClick(int x, int y) {
    int fScreenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    int fScreenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
    int dx = MulDiv(x, 65535, fScreenWidth);
    int dy = MulDiv(y, 65535, fScreenHeight);
    INPUT Input[2];
    memset(Input, 0, sizeof(INPUT));
    Input[0].type = Input[1].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    Input[0].mi.dx = Input[1].mi.dx = dx;
    Input[0].mi.dy = Input[1].mi.dy = dy;
    Input[0].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;
    Input[1].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;

    SendInput(2, Input, sizeof(INPUT));
}
```

EDIT:

VBA:
`SendInput`

```
Public Type MouseInput
    dx As Long
    dy As Long
    mouseData As Long
    dwFlags As Long
    time As Long
    dwExtraInfo As LongPtr
End Type

Public Type tagInput
    type As Long
    mi As MouseInput
End Type
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dx As Long, ByVal dy As Long, ByVal cButtons As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As LongPtr)
Public Declare PtrSafe Function SendInput Lib "user32" (ByVal cInputs As Long, pInputs As tagInput, ByVal cbSize As Long) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetSystemMetrics Lib "user32" (ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function MulDiv Lib "Kernel32" (ByVal nNumber As Long, ByVal nNumerator As Long, ByVal nDenominator As Long) As Long
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE As Long = 32768 'Can not use &H8000, because it was < 0
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = &H1
Public Const SM_CXSCREEN = 0
Public Const SM_CYSCREEN = 1
Public Const INPUT_MOUSE = 0


Public Sub MouseClick(ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long)
    Dim fScreenWidth As Long
    Dim fScreenHeight As Long
    Dim dx As Long
    Dim dy As Long
    Dim ret As Long
    
    fScreenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN)
    fScreenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)
    dx = MulDiv(x, 65535, fScreenWidth)
    dy = MulDiv(y, 65535, fScreenHeight)
    
    Dim MouseInput() As tagInput
    ReDim MouseInput(0 To 1) As tagInput
    
    MouseInput(0).type = INPUT_MOUSE
    MouseInput(0).mi.dx = dx
    MouseInput(0).mi.dy = dy
    MouseInput(0).mi.mouseData = 0
    MouseInput(0).mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE + MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN + MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE
    MouseInput(0).mi.time = 0
    MouseInput(0).mi.dwExtraInfo = 0
    
    MouseInput(1).type = INPUT_MOUSE
    MouseInput(1).mi.dx = dx
    MouseInput(1).mi.dy = dy
    MouseInput(1).mi.mouseData = 0
    MouseInput(1).mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE + MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP + MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE
    MouseInput(1).mi.time = 0
    MouseInput(1).mi.dwExtraInfo = 0
    
    
    ret = SendInput(2, MouseInput(0), LenB(MouseInput(0)))
    
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()
    MouseClick 481, 238
    MouseClick 336, 269
End Sub
```

`mouse_event`

```
Public Sub MouseClick(ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long)
    Dim fScreenWidth As Long
    Dim fScreenHeight As Long
    Dim dx As Long
    Dim dy As Long
    
    fScreenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN)
    fScreenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)
    dx = MulDiv(x, 65535, fScreenWidth)
    dy = MulDiv(y, 65535, fScreenHeight)
    
    mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE + MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN + MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, dx, dy, 0, 0
    mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE + MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP + MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, dx, dy, 0, 0
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes the target coordinates are clickable one excel sheet.
Can please let me know usage of above in VBA

Comment: Hi, mouse_event is useful but still I am not able to perform click operation with other task.
Kindly review my code, there I need to show message box after click. 
Can you please help me out in this?

Comment: *mouse_event is useful but still I am not able to perform click operation with other task.* I still can’t reproduce your problem. Could you use the paint tool to perform a test to see if the points are drawn. In addition, I found that if the excel does not have focus when clicking, the first click will only focus the window(could not click on the menu). Are you encountering this problem, or can you add a gif demo?

Comment: Wu , true, the cursor only focus over the mentioned coordinates instead of clicking it.
Can you please help me out, so that I can click on mentioned coordinates in series and perform rest of task in code of VBA.

Comment: Try to focus on your excel window before clicking. with function like [`SetForegroundWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow)